# How to delete a stubborn file in UNIX

Tags: unix, permissions, delete-file

I have this pesky file `qmasterd` that I just cannot delete, and I've tried a lot...

The file has these permissions:

```
-r-sr-sr-x 1 root daemon 280688 27 Apr 2007 qmasterd
```

When I try to `chmod, chgrp, or chown` all I get is something like this (note I'm trying to change the SUID here):

```
$ sudo chmod g-s qmasterd

 chmod: Unable to change file mode on qmasterd: Operation not permitted
```

Ideas please?

Comment: Do you have rights for writing in the dir? Try `touch YesICan`.

Comment: Yep, can create files in the directory and delete them. It's just this pesky file that can't be deleted.

Comment: Can you see if a process is using the fule `fuser -v path/qmasterd` ? Or look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52618/57293

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your **filesystem** is read-only or drive is broken. When linux starts and detects errors on drive, it tries to deal with it in read-only mode. Try checking disk for errors.

Comment: Sorry that’s not it. The system is fine. This is likely something super specific related to permissions, and maybe SUID...